# Nvidia GeForce Experience possible on Ubuntu? (13.10)

Tags: nvidia

New to Ubuntu and wondering if anyone else has been able to install Nvidia GeForce Experience on their ubuntu. (Preferably without WINE).

http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience

I haven’t been able to find any documentation on the internet about it, and haven't yet acquired the technical skills to figure it out by myself unfortunately.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have a GTX 660 if that information is at all relevant.

Comment: from what I gather huge benefit of GeForce Experience is ease of installing Nvidia drivers ...  years ago it was difficult to install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu however today its extremely easy ... Settings -> Software & Updates ->  Additional Drivers -> ... give it a few  seconds to warm up ... -> pick lastest Nvidia driver from list  ... Done !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the features offered by Geforce Experience are designed exclusively for Windows.

Since it deals with hardware drivers and settings for Windows-only games, there also is no need for it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes I suppose so, I have used it for the recording functions too, but I didn't think about the fact they were windows only games that were being optimised anyway. So it's probably just as easy to find a different recording software (the one with experience wasn't anything special anyway, I just grew accustomed to using it along with the other features. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

One of the best features about geforce experience is that it makes updating the drivers easy (as well as detecting the video card). I would be happy to see something in Ubuntu that when run, detected any Nvidia cards, worked out what drivers were needed, downloaded them and installed them. At the moment the Nvidia drivers are a pain in Ubuntu, if they could get this all working and stable, that would rock!

Comment: This is not answer, it is a comment, you posted it wrongly!

Comment: years ago it was difficult to install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu however today its extremely easy ... Settings -> Software & Updates ->  Additional Drivers -> ... give it a few  seconds to warm up ... -> pick lastest Nvidia driver from list  ... Done !!!

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to compile a version of OBS with NVENC to use your graphic card to encode what OBS record : just download this script [script link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6xRarshdokBVEpHYmRXYS1WazA) and run the following command `./install_ffmpeg-nvenc_obs.sh`in your download folder and that will install you OBS with NVENC support [OBS-NVENC.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Qbl.png) called OBS-PORTABLE

Comment: The script link leads to a Google doc requiring access permission. If the script is too long to be included on StackOverflow, please use Pastebin or make a gist.